# Cannot update SQL Server with VB.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Reservation
   Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection

Private Sub Reservation_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    sqlConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|EasyReserv.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim addSQL As String = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (  customerID, name, contactNumber, email ) VALUES (1, 'James', '012444444','james@gmail.com')"
    Dim addCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(addSQL, sqlConn)
    sqlConn.Open()
    addCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlConn.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

There is no error inside the code, and `ExecuteNonQuery` also returns 1, but there is no record in my database.

Comment: What happens if you change the datatype of `customerID` to add `identity` and then query `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` immediately after making the insertion?

Comment: the database still not updated

Comment: How do you check if the record is inserted or not? Are you looking at your table using Server Explorer inside VS IDE? If so, the connection string used by Server Explorer is the same connection string used by your application?

Comment: I check inside the database table after I end my application, anyway, problem solved. Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation is quite common. Your connection string is  `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|EasyReserv.mdf`.
This means that the MDF file, used by your program, is located in the folder pointed by the substitution string |DataDirectory| which is BIN\DEBUG or BIN folder depending if your application is an ASP.NET app or a WinForms app. [(See Where is DataDirectory)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/). The insert works as expected, but you have your MDF file connected by the Server Explorer in another directory (usually the project folder). So, if you look at the database with the Server Explorer you don't see the added record. Also check if the property `Copy To Output Directory` for the MDF file is set to `Never` or `Copy if Newer`, otherwise you risk to loose every change made by your program at every restart of your application while debugging in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
        con.Open()
        global_command = New SqlCommand("UPDATE products_tbl set running_no = '" & txt_running.Text & "' where template_code = 'n'and prod_no = '" & txt_product.Text & "'", con)
        global_command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        global_command.Dispose()

        MsgBox("Successfully updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Message")
        where = vbNullString

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Trace No 4: System Error or Data Error!" + Chr(13) + ex.Message + Chr(13) + "Please Contact Your System Administrator!", vbInformation, "Message")
    End Try


End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Before closing SqlConn try to extract the inserted customer using SqlDataReader. Maybe you are checking if the record is inserted or not in the wrong database.